# Handling unknown key value pairs in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application which I'm migrating to use Laravel, URLs can have varying structures, for example both this:

```
/nightowl/search/endtimefrom/3/endtimeto/7/region/EBAY-GB/catid/ALL/pagenumber/1/
```

And this:

```
/nightowl/search/endtimefrom/3/endtimeto/7/region/EBAY-GB/keyword/frogs/
```

Would both be valid URLs, the current router is part of the YAF framework, and the route is as follows:

```
"/:tool/search/*"
```

Which provides an array to the controller, with everything after `'/search/'` being a key value pair.

I've been bashing my head against a wall trying to work out how this is done in Laravel, it's beginning to feel like it might not be possible!

If it isn't, how should I go about making it possible?!

Comment: Firstly - I know nothing about Laravel. That said - MVC frameworks all have different ways of dealing with URLs like this, e.g. in CakePHP the format is `/controller/action/param:value/param:value/param:value`. My thoughts are that if Laravel uses a different URL structure than the one you are currently using, you may need to write a script that will blow that URL up into the appropriate sections yourself and convert it into Laravel's structure...

Comment: Hi @scrowler, I was worrying that that could be the case!
It does feel like it's only really intended to handle actions that will always have similar sets of parameters. In cake would those pairs have to have been defined in advance? 
Or would they simply be usable as the param name is included in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your thoughts and suggestions @scrowler and @Hailwood!
I'd been suspecting Laravel didn't support key => value pairs in the URL, but wasn't sure if I'd just missed something!

Having gone through your ideas, I think that it might be better to handle it within a closure of a route, like this, it feels closer to the place it belongs, but I'd love to hear any feedback on it:

```
Route::get('/{tool}/{action}/{arguments}', function(
    $tool, $action, $argumentsString)
{
    $arguments = \Utilities\UrlTools::urlToArgs($argumentsString);
    $arguments['tool'] = $tool;
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('SearchController', [$arguments]);
    $action = "{$action}Action";
    return $controller->$action();
})
->where('action', '(index|search|redirect)')
->where('arguments', '(.*)');
```

With the following function actually building the array of parameters:

```
public static function urlToArgs($urlString)
{
    $url = explode("/", trim($urlString,"/"));
    $i = 1;
    $key = '';
    foreach ($url as $url_segment) {
        if($i == 1) {
            $key = $url_segment;
            $i = 0;
        }
        else {
            $request[$key] = $url_segment;
            $i = 1;
        }
    }
    return($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel does not have a way to map the `key => value` from the url in that way so you have a couple of choices.

1) Modify your app so it creates the urls of 
/nightowl/search?endtimefrom=3&endtimeto=7&region=EBAY-GB&catid=ALL&pagenumber=1

2) Parse the route yourself before laravel has a chance to map the route.
Specifically I am referring to hijacking the current request, parsing out the url, rewriting it to the above format and then replacing the current request instance in Laravel.

3) Do it in the controller (probably the easiest)
Using a route of `Route::get('{tool}/search/{params?}', 'SearchController@doSearch')`

You can then parse in it your controller

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function doSearch($tool, $params = '')
    {
        $params = explode('/', $params);
        $mappedParams = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i+2){
            $mappedParams[$params[$i]] = $params[$i+1];
        }

        //$params should now contain a key/value map
    }

}
```

So with this route nightowl/search/endtimefrom/3/endtimeto/7/region/EBAY-GB/keyword/frogs

In your controller you would be up with

```
$tool:         nightowl
$mappedParams: Array
(
    endtimefrom => 3
    endtimeto   => 7
    region      => EBAY-GB
    keyword     => frogs
)
```

With this route nightowl/search/endtimefrom/3/endtimeto/7/region/EBAY-GB/catid/ALL/pagenumber/1

In your controller you would be up with

```
$tool:         nightowl
$mappedParams: Array
(
    endtimefrom => 3
    endtimeto   => 7
    region      => EBAY-GB
    catid       => ALL
    pagenumber  => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, the URL structure you are using might not be how Laravel does their own arguments/parameters in query strings. For example, CakePHP format is `/controller/action/param:value/param:value/` etc.

You might need to write you own code snippet to convert your URL into a format Laravel will recognise. [Here's an example of how to do that](https://eval.in/155446):

```
$test = '/nightowl/search/endtimefrom/3/endtimeto/7/region/EBAY-GB/keyword/frogs/';
$test = trim($test, '/'); // remove first and last slashes if present

// break up URL by slashes
$bits = explode('/', $test);

// get controller and action
$controller = $bits[0];
$action = $bits[1];

// remove from array - only arguments are left
unset($bits[0], $bits[1]);

$temp = array_values($bits);
$arguments = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++) {
  // if it's an even number then it should be a key
  if($i % 2 == 0 && isset($temp[$i + 1])) 
      $arguments[$temp[$i]] = $temp[$i + 1];
}

echo 'Controller: ' . $controller . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Action: ' . $action . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Arguments: ';
print_r($arguments);
```

You could then use those variables to construct a new URL for Laravel to interpret internally. Example output from this:

```
Controller: nightowl
Action: search
Arguments: Array
(
    [endtimefrom] => 3
    [endtimeto] => 7
    [region] => EBAY-GB
    [keyword] => frogs
)
```

## Edit:

A quick look through the Laravel docs makes me think that it's not set up to use key/value pairs in the parameters of the URL. Take a look at this question on SO that discusses the same thing and goes with using GET variables instead: [Can I have a variable number of URI parameters or key-value pairs in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777947/can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-uri-parameters-or-key-value-pairs-in-laravel-4)